# How can I optimize the query below which uses three levels of select statements?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

How to optimize the below query:

I have two tables, 'calendar_table' and 'consumption', Here I use this query to calculate monthly consumption for each year.

The calendar table has day, month and year for years 2005 - 2009 and consumption table has billed consumption data for monthly bill cycle.  This query will count the number of days for each bill and use that the find the consumption for each month.

```
SELECT id,
        date_from as bill_start_date,
        theYear as Year,
        MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(theMonth, '%m')) as month, 
        sum(DaysOnBill),
        TotalDaysInTheMonth,
        sum(perDayConsumption *  DaysOnBill) as EstimatedConsumption 
    FROM
    ( 
     SELECT
        id,
        date_from,
        theYear,
        theMonth,  # use theMonth for displaying the month as a number
        COUNT(*) AS DaysOnBill,
        TotalDaysInTheMonth, 
        perDayConsumption
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            c.id,
            c.date_from as date_from,
            ct.dt,
            y AS theYear,
            month AS theMonth,
            DAY(LAST_DAY(ct.dt)) as TotalDaysInTheMonth,
            perDayConsumption
        FROM
            consumption AS c
            INNER JOIN
            calendar_table AS ct
                ON ct.dt >= c.date_from
                    AND ct.dt<= c.date_to
        ) AS allDates
    GROUP BY
        id,
        date_from,
        theYear,
        theMonth ) AS estimates
GROUP BY
        id,
        theYear,
        theMonth;
```

It is taking around 1000 seconds to go through around 1 million records. Can something be done to make it faster?.

Comment: in your calendar_tables... the "dt" column is that a date/time? and if so, is it really just a date where all the "time" portions are 12:00:00am (midnight/beginning of day)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query is a bit dubious pretending to do one grouping first and then building on that with another, which actually isn't the case.

First the bill gets joined with all its days. Then we group by bill plus month and year thus getting a monthly view on the data. This could be done in one pass, but the query is joining first and then using the result as a derived table which gets aggregated. At last the results are taken again and "another" group is built, which is actually the same as before (bill plus month and year) and some pseudo aggregations are done (e.g. sum(perDayConsumption *  DaysOnBill) which is the same as perDayConsumption *  DaysOnBill, as SUM sums one record only here).

This can simply written as:

```
SELECT
  c.id,
  c.date_from as bill_start_date,
  ct.y AS Year,
  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(ct.month, '%m')) as month,
  COUNT(*) AS DaysOnBill,
  DAY(LAST_DAY(ct.dt)) as TotalDaysInTheMonth,
  SUM(c.perDayConsumption) as EstimatedConsumption
FROM consumption AS c
INNER JOIN calendar_table AS ct ON ct.dt BETWEEN c.date_from AND c.date_to
GROUP BY
  c.id,
  ct.y,
  ct.month;
```

I don't know if this will be faster or if MySQL's optimizer doesn't see through your query itself and boils it down to this anyhow.

Comment: @Strawberry: Well, the columns y and month are selected from either consumption or calendar_table. I find it more likely to be a convenience field in calendar_table.

Comment: Would you have a column called month in a calendar table?

Comment: @Strawberry: Haha, *I* wouldn't. But it seems that additionally to the date (dt) there is also the corresponding year (y) and month (month) stored in the table. Probably for the convenience of not having to extract these two values from dt every time.

Comment: The query works!!, it took around 600 seconds to process 1 million records. Thank you..